# How do I integrate react js in play web app

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, reactjs, playframework

I am trying to create a web application using play framework and I want to use react js for the frontend. How do I integrate react js in my play web application?

Answer (score 0):

I have zero knowledge about play framework but it is not that hard to integrate react in your web application.

if you have compiled reactjs JS file. just include in header tag in your index page. and declare div with ID. and then do some code like this

html

```
<div id="root">
 <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

reactjs

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

demo : http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/rrpgNB?editors=1010

and this blog article might be helpful to solve your problem
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way for managing dependencies in a Play app is through WebJars. First, add WebJars dependency to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1-2"
)
```

Now you must declare asset routes in the `routes` file

GET  /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET  /webjars/*file  controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)

Then you can add react to the HTML file:

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react", "react.js"))'></script>
</head>
```